# Unable to authenticate JWT in Ruby on Rails with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, jwt

I'm currently having trouble authenticating my Jason Web Token in Ruby on Rails 5.0.1. I'm using devise and jwt gems to validate the jwt generated for the user during log-in.

```
SessionController

       def create
         self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
         set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
         sign_in(resource_name, resource)
         yield resource if block_given?
         respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
         jwt_create
      end

        def jwt_create
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])
        if user.valid_password? params[:user][:password]
        token = JsonWebToken.encode(sub: user.id)
        flash[:notice] = "JWT Key: #{token}"
        end
      end
```

I'm currently using this to encode and decode my payload.

```
class JsonWebToken
  def self.encode(payload)
    payload['exp'] = 2.hours.from_now.to_i
    JWT.encode(payload, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)
  end

  def self.decode(token)
    JWT.decode(token, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)
  end
end
```

And authenticating as a before_action with the following:

```
protected
  def authenticate_request!
    unless user_id_in_token?
      render json: { errors: ['Not Authenticated'] }, status: :unauthorized
      return
    end
    @current_user = User.find(auth_token[:user_id])
  rescue JWT::VerificationError, JWT::DecodeError
    render json: { errors: ['Not Authenticated'] }, status: :unauthorized
  end

  private
  def http_token
    @http_token ||= if request.headers['Authorization'].present?
                      request.headers['Authorization'].split(' ').last
                    end
  end

  def auth_token
    @auth_token ||= JsonWebToken.decode(http_token)
  end

  def user_id_in_token?
    http_token && auth_token && auth_token[:user_id].to_i
  end

end
```

I'm not sure if my logic is flawed or I'm missing a key part to validate JWT. Any help would be greatly appreciated.